# get Activity name from database and create intent

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I am creating an app in which user can bookmark the activity. For that purpose I Stored the activity name to database and successfully fetch it. But After That I don't know how to set intent using that activity name
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you save only class name or fully qualified class name of activity?

Comment: I just saved that class name

Comment: String activityName = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
this is the code through which I get my class name

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code by which you can start activity using the name of the activity

```
String activityToStart = "Your Activity Name";
  try {
    Class<?> c = Class.forName(activityToStart);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
    startActivity(intent);
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignored) {
}
```